# What's a quick-and-dirty way to obtain an adapting iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, range, adapter

I have some (templated) iterator pair `Iterator begin1` and `Iterator end1`. I have a function foo, with signature

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
void foo(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end);
```

which does something on that range. Now, I want to have `foo` act not on the actual range elements, but rather on a transformation of these elements by some lambda or some function `bar`. I *can't* use std::transform or otherwise use temorary storage for the transformed values, since that would take up too much space or since I'm not allowed to allocate anything on the heap.

Now, I know I can implement some kind of adapting iterator myself, but I'd rather use something ready-made and not reinvent the wheel.

So, what's a quick and dirty way to get an appropriate adapting iterator pair I can pass for `foo` to do what I want? i.e. for me to be able to call

```
foo(magic(begin), magic(end))
```

or

```
auto new_pair = magic(begin, end);
foo(new_pair.first, new_pair.second);
```

?

Comment: Try @eric-niebler's [range-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) which will eventually be coming to the standard!

Comment: [boost Iterator Adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) is an other alternative

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: Can you be more specific/explicit and make that into an answer?

Comment: @einpoklum OK, done.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: I already +1 you my friend :-) ... but it's only quick and dirty based on an impressive, but still somewhat obscure as far as packages are concerned, dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Niebler's [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library provides a very nice solution for this, and is planned to be included in a future standard.  Here's a simple example:

```
std::vector<int> vi{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
using namespace ranges;
auto rng = vi | view::transform([](int x){ return x % 2; });
foo(rng.begin(), rng.end());  // When foo dereferences these iterators, it
                              // will see: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0].
```

This is all lazy and efficient, by the way. :)

Comment: ! I knew about the library and I've read his blog sometimes, but I didn't know of that syntax!! It's amazing. It won't be too hard to simulate command chains like `cat | grep | cup` with that syntax.